# AsyncStorage & Drawer render always null

Tags: javascript, react-native, asyncstorage

I have a login screen with a button remember me and when I connect, I would like to store this info in asynsctorage like this:

```
    if (this.isFormValid()) {
      AccountService.login(login, password)
        .promise.then(body => {
          console.log('onLoginClick -> body', body)
          Keyboard.dismiss()
          AsyncStorage.setItem('login', login)
          if (this.state.isRememberMeSelected) {
            console.log("i'm in the storage !")

            AsyncStorage.multiSet([['login', login], ['password', 
              password], ['isRememberMeSelected', '1']])
          } else {
            AsyncStorage.multiSet([['login', ''][('password', '')], 
            ['isRememberMeSelected', '0']])
          }
```

when I go back to my Drawer, I try to read the storage and get my value "isRememberMeSelected" :

```
 async componentDidMount() {
    // await AsyncStorage.getItem('login').then(value => {
    //   console.log('DrawerLogin', value)
    //   //this.setState({login: value})
    // })
    // await AsyncStorage.getItem('password').then(value => {
    //   console.log('DrawerPassword', value)
    //   //this.setState({password: value})
    // })
    await AsyncStorage.getItem('isRememberMeSelected').then(value => {
      console.log('DrawerIsRememberMeSelected', value)

      this.setState({isRememberMeSelected: value})
    })

    // await AsyncStorage.getAllKeys((err, keys) => {
    //   console.log(' Allkeys', keys)
    // })
    }
```

in me drawer, I check the value "isRememberMeSelected" to remove some items:

```
  StorageMultiRemove = async () => {
       try {
         await AsyncStorage.multiRemove(['refreshToken', 
         'stripeCustomerId', 'token'], err => {
           console.log(' Dans multiRemove Error', err)
         })
       } catch (error) {
         // Error saving data
       }
     }
```

```
        isRememberMeSelected === '1' ? this.StorageMultiRemove() : 
         AsyncStorage.clear()
```

when I go back in my drawer, this value and always null EXCEPT if I leave the app and relaunch ... there everything is well set....

I fit well in my condition (the one before doing my setItem) ...

I would like to record this data in asynStorage, return to my drawer and have these values ​​available

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a variable that will change when asyncstorage has been fetched

```
class Myform extends React.Component {
  state = {
    loading: true
}
```

then in component did mount update the state

```
 componentDidMount() {
    await AsyncStorage.getItem('isRememberMeSelected').then(value => {
      console.log('DrawerIsRememberMeSelected', value)
      this.setState({
        isRememberMeSelected: value,
        loading: false
       })
    })
  }
```

and in render

```
render() {
   if(loading) return;  // could return loading spinner or something
}
```